# Matlab RGB Color Values

Tags: matlab, rgb

in Matlab,

```
images=imread('images.jpg')
```

this image is installed smoothly, but I have pictures to get the RGB color values
`load ('images.jpg')` function returns a null value...

what can i do?

Comment: `load` is for .mat files.  Please clarify what exactly is wrong with `imread`.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the MATLAB documentation for imread.  Searching through for RGB options for a handy example such as:

Read indexed image and convert it to an RGB image.

```
[cdata,map] = imread( filename ) 
if ~isempty( map ) 
   cdata = ind2rgb( cdata, map ); 
end
```

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html

Comment: The first two dimensions are xy, the third dimension are the colors.